# Tiled OSM's - find the bounds of given city/state

Tags: openstreetmap

I used the overpass api to downloaded a couple of tiled pieces of USA's map  and now that I have the USA map locally, I would like to obtain the bounds of a given city (or state) without involving the API.

Should I search for certain tags, or relations? I assume I'll have to start from a node tagged (`k=name`, `v=city_name`) and (`k=place`, `v=city`), and based on it's `id` to find a `way` node.

Is my assumption correct? If yes, can you give me some directions on what should I look for once I have the node corresponding to the city?

Note. I went through the OSM wiki and studied a little bit the OSM XML format, however I was not able so far to have a whole picture of the OSM XML structure, so perhaps someone who has more experience with this can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Administrative boundaries are mapped as [ways](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way) or [relations](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation) with a [boundary=administrative](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dadministrative) tag. The boundary type is specified by an [admin_level](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dadministrative#admin_level). The admin_level value for cities differs from country to country and can even include multiple values. But for most countries, admin_level values for cities range from 6 to 8 (for the US it starts even from 5). In contrast, US states have an admin_level of 4. With the help of these keys you can construct a Overpass query for specific cities/stares, or even query for all cities and states. Here is an [example for Denver](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/9d9):

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  way["boundary"="administrative"]["admin_level"~"6|7|8"]["name"="Denver"];
  relation["boundary"="administrative"]["admin_level"~"6|7|8"]["name"="Denver"];
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

You can see that it will yield multiple results. Look at the [place](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:place) and admin_level tags to determine the importance of your results.

Alternatively you can use a geocoder as for example [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim). Here is an [example for Denver](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?city=Denver&limit=1&format=xml&polygon=1&addressdetails=1). In contrast to Overpass API, Nominatim will weight the results by importance. It also supports multiple output formats and can return polygons (which you can use for determining the bounds). Please read about Nominatim's [usage policy](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim_usage_policy) when using the instance at nominatim.openstreetmap.org.

And also see [search engine results](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=openstreetmap%20overpass%20city%20boundary).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Do you think it would be possible to process the local OSM XML downloaded files in order to find the `administrative` nodes?

Comment: Of course, just search for the tags I mentioned. And as already contained in my answer, these are not nodes but ways or relations.

Comment: Thanks, I was referring to the general `xml node` term than to the `Node` tag from OSM.

Comment: The OSM wiki explains the [OSM XML structure](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML). You have to search for a `<relation>`s or `<way>`s containing the `<tag>`s mentioned in my answer. Keep in mind that relations and ways don't have a geometry themselves. Instead relations have `<member>`s pointing to way and node IDs. Ways in turn have `<nd>`s pointing to node IDs. Only nodes have latitude and longitude. To get a better understanding of all this, grab a really small OSM XML file and take a look at it. It might help you if you open the same area in an OSM editor, for example iD or JOSM.